# 2 Datasets in 1 Report using Report Viewer?

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

How do I use 2 datasets in 1 report which is .rdlc?
I am using report viewer in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: u have any possibility to merge do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Create different `ReportDataSource` and add them to `.LocalReport.DataSources` of your `ReportViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also merge your datasets

```
ex.
'Private ds As New Dataset1
'Private ds2 As New Dataset2

.....

 ds.Merge(ds2) 
 rv_1.LocalReport.DataSources.add(ds)
```

refer to msdn.microsoft.com library here about [DataSet.Merge Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Merging DataSet Contents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszytsd8(v=vs.110).aspx)